# finding probability of joint distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am given a joint density function of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which is as follows:

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) & \quad 2<x <6, 0<y<5  \\
            0 & \quad\text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now I want to calculate the probability $P(X+Y < 4)$. Will I do it like this?:

$$       \int_{0}^{4}\int_{2}^{4}    \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dxdy      $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically an exercise on multiple integrals, and in these cases you would realise that your job becomes easier if you can picture the desired region of integration.

Proceed step by step to focus on the domain of integration.

\begin{align}
P(X+Y<4)&=E\left[\mathbf1_{X+Y<4}\right]
\\&=\iint \mathbf1_{x+y<4}\,f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\\&=\frac{1}{210}\iint \mathbf1_{x+y<4}\,(2x+y)\mathbf1_{2<x<6,\,0<y<5}\,dx\,dy
\\&=\frac{1}{210}\iint (2x+y)\,\mathbf1_{x+y<4,\,2<x<6,\,0<y<5}\,dx\,dy
\end{align}

This is how the region $\{(x,y):x+y<4,\,2<x<6,\,0<y<5\}$ looks like:

[image]

Can you evaluate the double integral now, keeping any one of $x$ and $y$ fixed at a time depending on ease of computation ?

Comment: so what will be the limits over the integrals?

Comment: @AhmadQayyum You tell me.

Comment: will these be the limits?:  $$       \int_{0}^{4-x}\int_{2}^{4}    \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dxdy      $$

Comment: after i solved it i got the final expression as: $    \frac{1}{210}(x-16)(x-4)   $. Is it correct or do I have to solve it further?

Comment: @AhmadQayyum Sorry, it is rather $$\int_2^4 \int_0^{4-x}...\,dy\,dx$$ Since you are keeping $x$ free and $y$ dependent on $x$, you have to integrate wrt $y$ first and then $x$.

Comment: that's what i thought. anyway thanks @StubbornAtom

Answer (score 3):

No, that integral gives $\mathbb{P}(2\leq X\leq 4,\, 0\leq Y \leq 4)$. For example, this includes $(4,4)$ which clearly does not satisfy $X + Y < 4$. You're integrating over a rectangular region, you should be integrating over a triangular region. Try

$$
\int_2^4\int_0^{4-x} \frac{1}{210}(2x+y)\,dy\,dx
$$

Comment: You're right, edited. Thanks!